# NSManagedObjectContext: exception breakpoint stops at save: method, but no log/crash/error

Tags: objective-c, core-data

I'm using CoreData in a multi-threaded iOS-app, and everything seems to work fine - unless I switch on the exception breakpoint in XCode. Whenever I do some CoreData-work, the breakpoint stops at the `save:`-method on `NSManagedObjectContext` - but the NSError is nil afterwards. I also have nothing in the log (except: `Catchpoint 2 (exception thrown).`), the app doesn't crash... So it's pretty hard to tell what's going wrong.

The only clue I have is that I have a single object in `updatedObjects:` in my `NSManagedObjectContext` - but there seems nothing wrong with it.

My question is very similar to [this question on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7007660/nsmanagedobjectcontext-save-doesnt-crash-but-breaks-on-objc-exception-throw)
, but the only answer there doesn't help me; I'm pretty sure that I've got everything covered there.

What could be wrong here? Or are there other possibilities to get some error information?

Thank you very much!

**EDIT**: showing code is pretty difficult. I'm loading objects with objectID, edit and store them in the context assigned to the current thread. I already checked - the context is always correct for the current thread; each thread has its own context, that shouldn't be the problem. It would be even helpful if only someone could tell me how to get more information from that error/exception - or if I have to care about it after all. It seems to me as if the exception is catched within the `save´-method, so probably its a "normal" behaviour?

Comment: @shannoga showing code is impossible, I fear - but see my edit, thanks...

Comment: are you using the same managedObjectContext among threads? (context can't be shared among threads)

Comment: @daveoncode - no; I'm pretty sure that each thread has it's own managedObjectContext. All I'm sharing is the managedObjectID, not contexts and no objectModels.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

This is *normal* behavior. CoreData uses exception throwing & handling internally for some of its program flow. I talked to the CoreData people about this. It may seem odd, but that's a design decision they made a long time ago.

When you hit the exception, make sure there's none of your code in the backtrace between your call to `-[NSManagedObjectContext save:]` and the exception being thrown. Calling `-save:` is very likely to call back into your code, e.g. if you're observing `NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification`, and if you're doing bad things when you're handling those notification, obviously you're at fault.

If you're exiting the `-save:` method, and the return value is `YES`, everything is good.

Please note, that you should check the return value, do *not* use `error != nil` to check for an error. The correct check is:

```
NSError *error = nil;
BOOL success = [moc save:&error];
if (!success) {
    // do error handling here.
}
```

Comment: is there no way to avoid this? it's pretty annoying while debugging, because I'd like to have an exception breakpoint on all the time. This way, it often stops without being a "real" exception...

Comment: No, there's no way to avoid this. It's just how CoreData works. You can file a radar and ask Apple to change the code. They're aware of it, but it's probably not very high on the CoreData team's priority list.

Comment: really? I mean - do you have some source for this? That would be disappointing, because - as I mentioned before - it's annoying while debugging :/

Comment: Thanks! This has saved me many painful hours of trying to figure out if I was doing something wrong.

Comment: there should be an "inverse" break point checkbox in the breakpoint settings

Comment: I have been running with the `-com.apple.CoreData.ConcurrencyDebug 1` with no problems and all of a sudden the code stops at the exact same spot `try context.save()`. It doesn't seem to be a thread issue; however, how do I make sure that it is in fact NOT a thread issue? The code seems to work fine when the debug switch is off.

Comment: Ranting aside, I have a try catch block around my save() and I still get exceptions that cause app crashes. Could you let me know if using error and the return value could alleviate the problem? The exception stack logged by save are "-[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator _coordinator_you_never_successfully_opened_the_database_device_locked:]" . FYI, I currently don't use the return value of bool and not passing in error param.

Comment: is there any way to find out why this happens? Or is it possible that I need to take care of such an "exception"? It's weird that sometimes it happens and sometimes and doesn't, which makes me think as if there's an issue occurring sometimes

Comment: You can ignore these spurious breakpoints using the great technique in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19262247/798224

Answer (score 22):

You can avoid these useless breaks; as others have pointed out this is normal CoreData behavior (but highly annoying!)

1. Remove the "All Objective-C Exceptions" breakpoint
2. Add a Symbolic Breakpoint on `objc_exception_throw`
3. Set a Condition on the Breakpoint to `(BOOL)(! (BOOL)[[(NSException *)$eax className] hasPrefix:@"_NSCoreData"])`
4. I also like to add an action, debugger command, "po $eax" which usually prints out the exception details

$eax is the correct register for the simulator, $r0 works on devices. You can create two separate breakpoints and enable/disable them as appropriate.

See [Ignore certain exceptions when using Xcode's All Exceptions breakpoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14370632/) for the original answer

Comment: This apparently no longer works. Someone suggested that they had to use "name" in place of "className" but I get the same result. I get a real exception when I enable this. What is the new workaround? I am using the most recent SDK and Xcode.

Comment: Works for iOS 16.4  (BOOL)(! (BOOL)[[$arg2 description] contains:@"_NSCoreData"])

Answer (score 8):

I had a similar problem. Eventually, I figured out the problem:

I added an observer to **NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification** that got freed without removing itself from the notification center. When its memory got assigned to some other object, the notification center tried calling on that object and raised an exception because it couldn't find the right selector. This exception was "invisible" for some reason, but caused CoreData to raise its own exception.

A well placed **removeObserver:** call fixed the problem.

Hope this may help someone else who encounters this situation.

Comment: I had the same issue and it's been bugging me for as long as I can remember, thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue occur in my code. I finally discovered that the issue was due to my model having changed, and the `EncryptedCoreData` `NSPersistentStoreCoordinator` I was using wasn't set up for automatic migration, as I had been expecting with MagicalRecord in the past.

The only symptom was this break point, without any other messages. It was solved (temporarily) by deleting and reinstalling the app and permanently by adding model versions and the appropriate key (`NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption: true, NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption: true`) to my stack setup.

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with the same problem and what i found is the coordinator will throw an exception when there is a merge  problem. I have removed my merge policy (default is the error) and after that the error pointer is no longer nil when you call save. That also gave me confidence that my code is ok.