# Restkit: getting objc_exception_throw in saveContextToPersistentStore, RKManagedObjectRequestOperation.m

Tags: exception, save, nsmanagedobjectcontext, restkit-0.20

I am getting, just for once every app runtime, an exception in  the method saveContextToPersistentStore in RKManagedObjectRequestOperation.m: on line

```
success = [contextToSave save:&localError];
```

success is YES, localError is nil. I can continue the program execution in debugger.

I tried to wrap it with @try block but with no success (as something else took care of this) to get more information why it happens.

Can you help me to investigate the cause of this?  Is this something I should pay attention to? [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13236559/3389683) may targets this issues. But I am not sure, if the problem is local or caused in higher layers (Restkit mapping).

Stack:
[image]

Comment: Answer is here: [NSManagedObjectContext: exception breakpoint stops at save: method, but no log/crash/error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8337635/nsmanagedobjectcontext-exception-breakpoint-stops-at-save-method-but-no-log-c)